# Start with Text hidden, show text onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is all definitely over my head, but I had to ask.  All I really want to do, is to start out with the text hidden, have only the SHOW button, and click on it to show the text. It is for a French Dictée site, where someone listens to a French phrase, writes what he thinks he hears in a form text field, then clicks the SHOW button to see if he got it right.  I tried changing the P tag to visibility hidden, but then clicking on the SHOW button won't reveal it.

I searched under toggle, but none of the responses seemed to fit mine.

Here's the only answer from searching your site that comes close, but I can't make the text to start out hidden, then reveal it by clicking on the SHOW button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Barry

Okay, yes, I've seen that, but that still will open ANY P tag on the page with `display:none`.  What I want is to have individual passages capable of being revealed by clicking a button.  These HIDE and SHOW buttons open EVERY paragraph.

For example, on my site,

http://techno-french.com/learning-french-online-free/learn-french-with-mouse-trap-dictee

I have two passages, one in French and one in English.  I'd like users to be able to SHOW the French, while keeping the English hidden, and vice versa SHOW the English while keeping the French hidden.  Possible?  No?  Yes?

As always, thanks for any help.

Barry

Comment: If any of these answer helped you please do accept any of these as answer...

Answer (score 5):

Jquery hide and show can toggle element's `display` property only, not visibility. You can either make the element `display:none` initially or change the `visibility` instead of `hide/show`.

```
  var $p = $('p');
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $p.css('visibility', 'hidden');
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $p.css('visibility', 'visible');
  });
```

or just:

```
 $("#hide, #show").click(function(){
      $('p').css('visibility', this.id == "show" ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
  });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g8Y9j/)**

or in the initial style set

```
p{ /*This can vary based on which p you want to hide first*/
   display: none; /*Instead of visibility*/
}
```

and just a shortened version.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hide, #show").click(function () {
        $("p").toggle(this.id == "show");
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LEyBa/)**

*Note that display property will take the element out of the page flow there wont be space reserved for it, in case of visibility you will see the empty space reserved by the element*

Comment: Use this, but use the on.('click',function(){}) notation instead.

Comment: @KnowHowSolutions - using _.click()_ is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say thanks, so as much as I want to, I won't, but I would like to nuance how this works a bit.  Silly me, I thought all I needed to do was replace the "p" in the function above and then I could show and hide a div, which is really what I'd like to do.  This, sadly, doesn't work.  I know my knowledge of javascript should be better.  Here's what I get: http://techno-french.com/learn-french-online-free/resurecting-french-dictees-to-learn-french. I want the entire text to be white letters on blue background.

Comment: @BarryGlick Please show your complete code that is causing the issue in a fiddle demo.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what a fiddle demo is.  I can give you a link to the page: http://techno-french.com/learn-french-online-free/resurecting-french-dictees-to-learn-french.  The code is exactly as above except I tried placing the "p"with "div"

Comment: I am very sorry if I am not supposed to do it this way, but I edited my original post.  I am assuming that I shouldn't add to my question by using this comment box, right?  If you would please take a look at my revision, above, you will see I still haven't got quite the solution I'm looking for.  I hope there is one.  Thanks!

Comment: Whoops!  It seems I didn't scroll down far enough.  There appears to be another answer.  Let me see how it works.  Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah.  I tested the above suggestions and the SHOW and HIDE buttons simply turn on or off ANY P tag.  So, this won't work for me.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

try put the display:none will work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p style="display:none">If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer as well, however, what worked for me was this small code of JQuery:

```
<div style="display: none;" id="hiddenText">This is hidden</div>
<a href="#" onclick="$('#hiddenText').show(); return false;">Click here to show hidden 
text</a>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2nwesndm/)

[Source](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=700121)